# What is "Valor" in Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry potter and the Cursed Child*, people in alternate reality say "For Voldemort and Valor". What is "Valor"?

There is a graveyard named Valor but it seems irrelevant.

Comment: It's a word. It should be spelled "valour" since it's Britain. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/valour?s=t

Comment: Voldemort was a Pokémon Go player.

Comment: There is also a real-world alliterative fascist greeting that bears some curious similarities.

Comment: I'm more bothered by the fact that old Voldy lets his followers use the first part of the phrase. Jack Thorne acts like he never read the books.

Comment: @ibid - Maybe old Voldie mellowed once he'd won.

Answer (score 32):

### It has no special meaning

In this case, "valor" simply has its common meaning of "bravery." I would guess that "valor" was chosen since it starts with the same letter as "Voldemort," making for a nice alliterative motto. One might note some similarities with a [certain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_salute) alliterative greeting used by real-life supremacist groups.

It also recalls the slogan "Magic is Might," used by the Voldemort-controlled Ministry in *Deathly Hallows*.

> The great Atrium seemed darker than Harry remembered it. Previously a
> golden fountain had filled the center of the hall, casting shimmering
> spots of light over the polished wooden floor and walls. Now a
> gigantic statue of black stone dominated the scene. It was rather
> frightening, this was sculpture of a witch and a wizard sitting on
> ornately carved thrones, looking down at the Ministry workers toppling
> out of fireplaces below them. Engraved in foot-high letters at the
> base of the statue were the words MAGIC IS MIGHT.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

I cannot recall any mention of the word Valor as a place or character name in *Harry Potter*, so I doubt it has any further significance.

Comment: Not only does it not have any significance in relation to Voldemort, it also strikes me as a Gryffindor quality... Of course there would be no Gryffindor anymore at Hogwarts, but it's a quality associated with the Order of the Phoenix and the resistance, not Voldemort. So either it's only here for the alliteration (which, as many people pointed out, could well be a reference to fascism, but JKR loves alliterations anyway) or maybe it could mean that Voldemort has this sort of personality cult going on where he is the brave hero who saved the pure wizarding bloodlines.